# Facebook API permission not working

Tags: android, facebook, api

```
LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile",
            "user_location", "user_birthday", "user_likes", "user_friends",
            "user_status", "user_checkins", "read_friendlists",
            "user_groups", "user_interests", "user_activities"));
```

I have requested facebook api for using the following details of the user but it is not asking for these permissions instead its just saying facebook will access your public profile.

Comment: are you trying with an app admin?

Comment: Not sure what app admin means. can you help us out.

Comment: ...app admin = the user who created the app

Comment: Its working for app admin but not for other users

Answer (score 0):

Most permissions need to get approved by Facebook before they work for other users. Before approval, they will only work for users with a role in your App (Admin, Developer, Tester). Read about login review in the Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login

Also, `user_groups` will not get approved at all for Android:

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client
>   on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example,
>   Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In
>   addition, Web, Desktop and TV apps will not be granted this
>   permission.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-user_groups